# Pass Comparator in custom list Constructor, which is used to sort contents of the list

Tags: java, sorting, constructor, comparator

I'm working on an Assignment where we're to create our own Generic Linked List. The List takes a `Comparator<T>` in its constructor, and we are to use the compare method of that comparator in our sorting algorithm. I've got the List working and fully tested, but I'm having issues passing a comparator type.

Keeping in mind the comparator would be passed by an end-user, how would you define and pass a comparator?

The constructor looks like:
`public SorterList(final Comparator<T> comparator) {}`

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: When trying this, I get an error when creating the new SorterList object: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xm6N.png).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

       public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {

                // Ignore the simplicity of the compare
                if(o1 > o2)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return 1;

       }

    };

SorterList<Integer> intList = new SorterList<Integer>(comparator);

}
```

Comment: Well, you answered your own question, didn't you? A better type would be Comparator<? super T>, though. How to define a comparator entirely depends on the concrete type of T, and on how you want to compare elements, but that is irrelevant for the list.

Comment: I'm trying to test the list and it's implementation using JUnit to make sure everything is working, so that's why I'm interested in it. I think I understand what the comparator does, I just dont know how to pass it. I'll edit the code above with an example of the bug I'm running into.

Comment: What do you store in the list when you test it? How do you want to compare these elements. There must be millions of onlne examples showing how to sort a list. Have you googles and tried anything?

Comment: I'm not trying to sort a list or anything yet, my IDE is just complaining even when I try to pass the comparator into the constructor (Shown in image above)

Comment: The compare method is just temporary, I just wanted to get something down so it wouldnt complain about it. Also, the indentation is making it look odd. I'm using the comparator inside main, outside of the comparator declaration, isn't that OK?

Comment: It seems you defined your own Comparator interface, instead of using the standard java.util.Comparator one. It also seems you're defining your classes in the default package. Don't do any of that (and fix your indentation).

Comment: Ahah, importing `java.util.Comparator` fixed the issue. The indentation is fine in the IDE, it's being fidgetty in the actual post.

What do you mean by "Defining it in the default package"?

Comment: Your classes should be in a package. They should start with `package foo.bar.anything`. Also, your comparator implementation is wrong. You must respect the contract defined in the interface.

Comment: I understand my compare method is improper. It's temporary.

My teacher has specifically said we're not to use a package in our projects.